# How to fix padding for mobile compatibility?

Tags: css, wordpress

Sorry if this seems like an easy fix, I'm creating my first WordPress site and new to CSS. The theme I chose came with a countdown timer but it's not compatible on mobile.

I've tried to padding and margins but it does not seem to do me any good. I've tried searching into "@media", changing the padding and margins but I feel like I'm doing it all wrong, giving me no result.

Thanks!
[image: This is what it looks like on destop]
[image: This is what it looks like on mobile device]

```
#countdown {
margin-top: -100px; 
margin-bottom: -200px;
background: rgb(250,248,245, .75);
box-sizing:border-box;
}


.countdown-cdown-title,
#countdown h3 {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
color:  #1B2D66;
}


.countdown-digit{   
background: rgb(250,248,245, .5);
color:  #1B2D66;
border-color: rgb(27,45,102, .7);
}
```

Comment: Try using `display:block` on your `@media` for mobile (`@media` is the right way to go to limit some CSS to specific screen sizes). We don't have your HTML so I can't say exactly how it will work, but it should stack up your elements.

Comment: You might want to post more relevant code if you need help, especially what you have tried for mobile.